# Write a Program that Writes a function BUT in a different language!

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest program that takes one input (n) from STDIN (or equivalent) and outputs a simple incrementing function with one argument (x) that returns x + n but the function must be in a different language. Pretty simple!

**This is code-golf, normal rules apply, shortest program wins.**

Example: ><> to Python (Ungolfed)

```
!v"def i(x):"a"    return x+"ir!
 >l?!;o
```

Input:

```
3
```

Output:

```
def i(x):
    return x+3
```

EDIT: Anonymous functions and lambda expressions are allowed!

Comment: How big can the input get? As far as I can tell, your example only works with single digit numbers for the ><> half of it.

Comment: In theory in should be able to use any (reasonable) input, but answers that only use a input that could maintain 1 digit are fully acceptable, I did consider reworking the example to correct this before posting but i figured ill leave it for simplicity stake.

Comment: I don't see any definition for `function BUT` that we are supposed to write.. -_-

Comment: When a function returns another function, it's called a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7464475). I don't know if this applies cross-language, though...

Comment: @ETHproductions I guess the goal is not to return a function object, but the source code of a function in that other language.

Comment: @ETHproductions When a function returns another function *whose environment is extended to contain those bindings available to the outer function*, it's called a closure. But `int foo() { return 10; } int (*(bar)(int x))() { return &foo; }` ([help?](http://cdecl.org/)) does not contain a closure, because `foo` cannot access `x`. In particular, nested function *definitions* (lambda expressions, which evaluate to closures) are not valid standard C. This is why libraries like `pthread` let you supply a `void *state` to be passed to a callback—that's the only way to give it data.

Comment: @Blakusl Thanks for the accept, but unfortunately, since this is code golf, the shortest answer should be accepted, tiebroken by post time (that would be gs2 to K by Dennis atm).

Comment: So the first thing should be a full program, not a just a function, right?

Comment: @Sp3000 my bad, it must be obvious im new lol

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann correct, a full program whos output is a function

Comment: @Blakusl No worries - welcome! :D

Comment: Must the function be outputted in STDOUT or can it be outputted into a file?

Comment: you specify the output doesn't have to  be a full program but does the output have to compile?

Answer (score 26):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2) → K, 2 bytes

```
•+
```

This prints a tacit, monadic function. The source code uses the [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_page_437&oldid=565442465#Characters) encoding. [Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCiKw&input=NDI)

### Test run

```
$ xxd -c 2 -g 1 sum-func.gs2
00000000: 07 2b  .+
$ printf 42 | gs2 sum-func.gs2
42+
$ kona
K Console - Enter \ for help

  (42+) 69
111
  f : 42+
42+
  f 69
111
```

### How it works

#### GS2

- GS2 automatically reads from STDIN and pushes the input on the stack.
- `•` indicates that the next byte is a singleton string literal.
- Before exiting, GS2 prints all stack items.

#### K

Left argument currying is automatic in K.

Here, `n+` turns the dyadic function `+` into a monadic function by setting its left argument to `n`.

Comment: Which encoding are you using?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ "The source code uses the [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_page_437&oldid=565442465#Characters) encoding."

Answer (score 16):

## [ShapeScript](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript) → J, 4 bytes

```
"&+"
```

This prints a tacit, monadic verb. Try it online: [ShapeScript](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=IiYrIg==&input=NDI=), [J](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=42%26%2B%2069)

### Test run

```
$ cat sum-func.shape; echo
"&+"
$ printf 42 | shapescript sum-func.shape; echo
42&+
$ j64-804/jconsole.sh 
   42&+ 69
111
   f =: 42&+
   f 69
111
```

### How it works

#### ShapeScript

- ShapeScript automatically reads from STDIN and pushes the input on the stack.
- `"&+"` pushes that string on the stack.
- Before exiting, ShapeScript prints all stack items.

#### J

`&` performs argument currying.

Here, `n&+` turns the dyadic verb `+` into a monadic verb by setting its left argument to `n`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a language where you don't need the close-quote.

Comment: There's a good chance you're right, but I can't recall one with implicit input and implicit output.

Answer (score 12):

## GolfScript → CJam, 4 bytes

```
{+}+
```

This prints a code block (anonymous function). Try it online: [GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IjQyIiAjIFNpbXVsYXRlIGlucHV0IGZyb20gU1RESU4uCgp7K30r), [CJam](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=69%20%7B42%20%2B%7D%20~&input=42)

### Test run

```
$ cat sum-func.gs; echo
{+}+
$ printf 42 | golfscript sum-func.gs
{42 +}
$ cjam
> 69 {42 +} ~
111
> {42 +}:F; 69F    
111
```

### How it works

#### GolfScript

- GolfScript automatically reads from STDIN and pushes the input on the stack.
- `{+}` pushes that block on the stack.
- `+` performs concatenation, which happily concatenates a string and a block.
- Before exiting, GolfScript prints all stack items.

#### CJam

`{n +}` is a code block that, when executed, first pushes `n` on the stack, then executes `+`, which pops two integers from the stack and pushes their sum.

Comment: I was just going to post this!

Comment: Wow that's impressive. `{n +}` pushes `42`, then executes `+`. (Probably should be `{42 +}` or "pushes `n`")

Comment: @Justin Indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## BrainF*** to JavaScript ES6, 57 bytes

```
----[-->+++<]>--.[-->+<]>+.+.--[->++<]>.[--->+<]>+++.[,.]
```

(Assumes that the input is composed of numeric characters)

Say `1337` is your input. Then, this would compile to:

```
x=>x+1337
```

Answer (score 10):

## R to Julia, 19 bytes

```r
cat("x->x+",scan())
```

This reads an integer from STDIN using `scan()` and writes an unnamed Julia function to STDOUT using `cat()`. The Julia function is simply `x->x+n`, where `n` comes from the R program.

Answer (score 10):

## Rotor to K, 2 bytes

```
'+
```

Might as well jump in on the K bandwagon.

Answer (score 9):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o) to K, 5 bytes

```
i'++o
```

Thanks to **[@kirbyfan64sos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21009/kirbyfan64sos)**

Another version using features added after the challenge was created.

```
i'+
```

- Gets input, pushes to stack
- Pushes '+' as a string
- Outputs stack contents

Comment: K has automatic currying, so you can just do `i'++p`.

Comment: The distance between K and O is 4. You need to shorten it one byte.

Comment: @mbomb007 wat. The code is 5 bytes long

Comment: The letters. In the alphabet. Get it?

Comment: @mbomb007 that was too complicated for me

Answer (score 9):

## [Malbolge](http://zb3.github.io/malbolge-tools/#interpreter) to JavaScript ES6, 71 bytes

```
('&%@9]!~}43Wyxwvutsr)Mon+HGi4~fBBdR->=_]:[875t4rT}0/Pf,d*((II%GEE!Y}Az
```

It's always fun to generate Malbolge code.

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/9/F2clRRckipq622tLIMLSsrLRE21@/IC9PVUXZPSOjtka5ykE3oMwm9v9/AA "Malbolge – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat Not working; missing cat program part.

Comment: The original 71 bytes program is also missing cat part.

Answer (score 9):

## Minecraft 1.8.7 to K, <s>7</s> 6 + 33 + 27 + 62 = <s>129</s> 128 Bytes

This is using [this version of byte counting](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7397/44713).

[image: the system]

Command blocks (going from left to right):

```
scoreboard objectives add K dummy
```

```
scoreboard players set J K <input>
```

```
tellraw @a {score:{name:"J",objective:"K"},extra:[{text:"+"}]}
```

This could probably be golfed a little more, but it's fairly simple: generate a variable `J` with the objective `K` and set its score for that objective to the input (there is no STDIN - I figured this was close enough). Then, after a tick, output the score of the variable `J` for the objective `K` followed by a `+`. Easy peasy.

Comment: Note that the .dat bytecounting is _not_ applicable for this system, as the Minecraft version listed does not support structure files.

Comment: For the second one, couldn't you remove the `extra`, place the score JSON in an array, and place a string after? `tellraw @a [{score:{name:"J",objective:"K"}},"+"]`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Not at the time of submission, four years ago.

Answer (score 8):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously) to Python, 15 bytes

`,"lambda n:n+"+`

Expects input to be in string form, i.e. `"3"`

Explanation:

```
,: read value from input
"lambda n:n+": push this literal string
+: concatenate top two values on stack
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c226c616d626461206e3a6e2b222b&input=%223%22) (you will have to manually enter the input because the permalinks don't like quotes)

Comment: Hey, someone actually went through with Seriously! :D

Comment: Seriously? You finished Seriously before Simplex? D:

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ It's not fully finished yet (see the issue tracker), but it works well enough to use in some golfs.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth to APL, <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
+z"--
```

The Pyth code simply concatenates the input (`z`) with the string `"--"`. This creates an unnamed monadic train in APL with the form `n--`, where `n` comes from Pyth. When calling it in APL, `(n--)x` for some argument `x` computes `n--x = n-(-x) = n+x`.

Try: [Pyth](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bz%22--&input=3&debug=0), [APL](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u21903--%u22C4f%202&run)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 6):

## rs -> K, 2 bytes

```
/+
```

[Live demo.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%2F%2B&input=2)

Answer (score 5):

## [Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)) to Ruby, 19 bytes

```
?N:"->x{x+"N.!"}"$
```

Ungolfed:

```
? N:       ~ Read an integer from STDIN, store in N
"->x{x+"   ~ Write that string to STOUT
N. !       ~ Write N
"}"$       ~ Close bracket, end of program
```

This creates an unnamed Ruby function of the form `->x{x+n}` where `n` comes from Mouse.

Comment: Good job, I like this post.

Answer (score 5):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) to Python, 25 + 3 = 28 bytes

```
"v+x:x adbmal
o/?(3l
;>~n
```

Takes input via the `-v` flag, e.g.

```
py -3 fish.py add.fish -v 27
```

and outputs a Python lambda, e.g. `lambda x:x+27`.

For a bonus, here's an STDIN input version for 30 bytes:

```
i:0(?v
x+"r~/"lambda x:
o;!?l<
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica to C#, 22 bytes

```
"x=>x+"<>InputString[]
```

Outputs a C# `Func<int, int>` of form

```
x=>x+n
```

Comment: The output is valid Javascript (ES6/7) as well.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell to Mathematica, 14 bytes

```
(++"+#&").show
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth -> K, 4 bytes

```
+z\+
```

K is really easy to abuse here...

[Live demo.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bz%5C%2B&input=2&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck to Java, 273

```
+[----->+++++.+++++.++++++.[---->++++.+[->++++.-[->+++-.-----[->+++.+++++.++++++.[---->++++.-[--->++-.[----->++-.[->+++.---------.-------------.[--->+---.+.---.----.-[->+++++-.-[--->++-.[----->+++.,[.,]+[--------->+++.-[--->+++.
```

Outputs a method like `int d(int i){return i+42;}` (which doesn't *look* like a Java method, but... Java!)

Comment: Y'know, because Java.

Comment: What means, it doesn't look like a Java method? How else should that kind of method look?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann `public static int method(int argument){return argument+42;}`

Comment: Hmm, okay. (Though if you are programming only in `public static`, you are not really doing Java. `argument` would also better be named `summand` ;-). )

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I was just modelling `public static void main(String[] arguments){}`

Comment: Now make a full Java program ;)

Comment: "which doesn't look like a Java method" How so? It's just an overridable `int`-returning instance method that has one argument (an `int`) and no access modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

## POSIX shell to Haskell, 19 bytes

```
read n;echo "($n+)"
```

Anonymous functions being allowed, Haskell is a good output choice with the operator sections.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 to CJam, <s>18</s> 20 bytes

*Thanks to LegionMammal978 for correcting the functionality.*

```
print"{%f+}"%input()
```

The Python does a basic string format. `%f` is the code for a float, and since I wouldn't lose any bytes for handling floats, I went ahead and did so.

The CJam is much the same as the Golfscript->CJam answer. It looks something like this:

```
{7.4+}
```

or:

```
{23+}
```

It's a block that takes the top value off the stack, pushes the special number, then adds them.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 At the end of the question it says that anonymous functions and lambda expressions are allowed. Still, I'll edit my answer with an alternative full program.

Comment: The OP means that the output can be a function.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP → JavaScript (ES6), 20 <s>24</s> bytes

Reading from *STDIN* is always expensive in PHP. It looks a bit strange:

```
x=>x+<?fgets(STDIN);
```

It prints `x=>x+` and waits for user input to complete the string, terminates with the complete anonymous JavaScript function, e.g. `x=>x+2`.

**First version (24 bytes**)

```
<?='x=>x+'.fgets(STDIN);
```

Comment: Why not just `x=>x+<?=$x;`? It's valid PHP4.1 and you can pass the values over POST, GET, SESSION, COOKIE, ... and it will work flawlessly. Or on PHP5.3 with `register_globals=on` (on your `php.ini` file).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The requirements of the challenge say that it takes a number from `STDIN`. Every time I ignored that it was criticized. So I take requirements seriously now. :)

Comment: Well, I think that `GET` is passed over `STDIN`. I can test it in a while.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/187025/how-to-pass-get-variables-to-a-php-script-via-the-command-line/187038#187038 <-- Evidence on my claim. Just use the code I provided, slap this link and no one can complain

Comment: Ho, understood! That's clever, indeed!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript to [Lambda Calculus](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~lopes/teaching/inf212W12/readings/lambda-calculus-handout2.pdf), 39 bytes

(This uses the linked document as a basis.)

```
alert((x=>`λa(${x}(add a))`)(prompt()))
```

Say input is `5`. Then this becomes:

```
"λa(5(add a))"
```

Comment: Where is an interpreter for Lambda Calculus?

Comment: @feersum Check the link. I'm not sure if an actual interpreter exists, but I was told I was able to submit in this language.

Comment: What do you mean "you were told"? Answers that don't run in any language implementation are invalid.

Comment: @feersum [I asked; it has been done before.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25275163#25275163)

Comment: Lambda calculus being fairly well known, I assume there must be a valid interpreter somewhere. The point is, you need to identify such an interpreter and write the code in the format accepted by that interpreter.

Comment: @feersum Kay then. I might have time in an hour or two, school's being busy ticking me off.

Comment: lambda calculus interpreter = pencil and paper, which were the only computers available at the time it was invented.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina) to [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

Uses one file for each of these lines + 1 penalty byte; or, put both lines in a single file and use the `-s` flag.

```
$
+_
```

Matches the end of the input with `$` and puts `+_` there. This results in something of the form `3+_`, which is an anonymous function in Pip.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash → C/C++/C#/Java, 33 bytes

and maybe others

```
echo "int f(int a){return a+$1;}"
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Tiny Lisp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62886/2338) to [Ceylon](http://ceylon-lang.org/), <s>68</s> 61

```
(d u(q((n)(c(q(Integer x))(c(q =>)(c(c(q x+)(c n()))()))))))
```

Tiny Lisp doesn't have real input and output – it just has expression evaluation.
This code above creates a function and binds it to `u`.
You can then call `u` with the argument `n` like this: `(u 7)`, which will evaluate to this Tiny Lisp value:

```
((Integer x) => (x+ 7))
```

This is a valid Ceylon expression, for an anonymous function which adds 7 to an arbitrary integer.

<sup>*Thanks to DLosc for an improvement of 7 bytes.*</sup>

Comment: Nice job working with the very limited output capabilities!

Answer (score 2):

## [Microscript II](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript_II) to Javascript ES6, 9 bytes

```
"x=>x+"pF
```

Answer (score 2):

## GNU sed to C, 46 bytes

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)$/f(int x){return x+\1;}/'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy to K, 5 Bytes

\o/ K will be being used very soon if it can do this.

```
N'+'Z
```

or maybe...

```
N'+'O
```

If the input is taken as a string (only for 0-9 input)...

```
i'+'Z
```

All of these, for input 2, will output:

```
2+
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Ceylon](http://ceylon-lang.org/) to [Tiny lisp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62886/2338), 76

```
shared void run(){print("(q((x)(s ``process.readLine()else""``(s 0 x))))");}
```

This produces (after reading a line of input) output like `(q((x)(s 5(s 0 x))))`, which evaluates in Tiny Lisp to `((x) (s 5 (s 0 x)))`, a function which takes an argument `x`, subtracts it from 0, and subtracts the result from 5. <sub>(Yeah, this is how one adds in Tiny Lisp, there is only a subtraction function build in. Of course, one could define an addition function first, but this would be longer.)</sub>

You can use it like this as an anonymous function:

```
((q((x)(s 5(s 0 x)))) 7)
```

(This will evaluate to 12.)

Or you can give it a name:

```
(d p5 (q((x)(s 5(s 0 x)))))
(p5 7)
```

<sup>*Corrections and Golfing Hints from DLosc, the author of Tiny Lisp.*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt) → [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 5 bytes

```
U+"+x
```

This is pretty simple.

---

#### Explanation

```
U+     // Input added to the string...
  "+x  // This is the string
```

Comment: Japt → Japt would be not only a palindrome, but horizontally mirror-able: `U+"+U` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fith](https://github.com/nazek42/fith) to Forth, 28 bytes (non-competitive)

*Fith was created after the challenge was posted.*

```
": p " line " + ;" + + .
```

This pushes the first part, then reads the number, then pushes the last part. The two `+` words then concatenate the three strings, and `.` prints.

The output looks something like this:

```
: p 7 + ;
```

This defines a function named `p`, and as far as I know, it is the shortest method in Forth to define the necessary function.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) to [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```python
lambda n:n+'+'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZV6Kh8T8nMTcpJVEhzypPW11b/b@mRmZeQWmJhqam5n9jAA) Takes a string as input.

The Python function simply returns `'n+'`, where `n` is the input. In 05AB1E, pushes implicit input, push `n`, add them, and implicitly output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://GitHub.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) → [Squire](https://GitHub.com/Sampersand/squire), 13 bytes

```
O+"\(x)=>x+"P
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sOy8zPaNkwYKlpSVpuhZr_bWVYjQqNG3tKrSVAiBiUKkFy52dnSM8w7ggXAA)

Knighting this code will inquire thee, in which thou shalt enscribe numerals on thine keyboard. Whilst one can be a jest and use Arabic numerals, true royalties use Roman numerals, such as \$\text{CCCXIV}\$ <sup>(that's 314 for you jests)</sup>. (It doesn't matter as it is string concatenation - Squire parses both).

Upon striking the return key, the following journey shall be proclaimed:

```
\(x)=>x+CCCXIV
```

Some foreigners might entitle this as an 'anonymous lambda' but true Squire users lack this brash peasant vocabulary.

Squire program

```py
f=\(x)=>x+CCCXIV
# embark and proclaim
proclaim(f(X)) # CCCXXIV (314 + 10 = 414)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Chaîne](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Cha-ne) to JavaScript ES6, 7 bytes

Again, assumes numeric input.

```
x=>x+{i
~~~~~~~
x=>x+   ; write that text
     {  ; command sequence
      i ; read input and push to stack
        ; implicit: take top entry on stack and pushes it to writing string
        ; implicit: close }
        ; implicit: print string
```

Answer (score 1):

### Powershell to EmacsLisp, 37 bytes

```
function p($a){"(defun p(x)(+ $a x)"}
```

### EmacsLisp to Powershell, 44 bytes

```
(defun p(x)(format"function p($a){%s+$a}"x))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python to C++, <s>49 bytes</s> 39 bytes

```
print"[](int x){return x+%d;}"%input()
```

Thanks @Mego !

Basically,  this prints out lambda with the argument x and adds it to the input of the Python program.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6) > PHP/Javascript, <del>38</del> <del>48</del> 47 bytes

This code is an anonymous function that creates a **VALID** PHP and Javascript function called `anonymous`.

```
P=prompt;P(Function('$x',`return $x+${P()};`));
```

As of the writting of this code, only Firefox has implemented ES6 nativelly (without flags and suchs).

This code uses the `prompt()` function to request input and for output. Firefox supports copying the output of `prompt()`, making this a legitime output method for Javascript.

---

Considerations:

- The `;` at the end is required for PHP
- The space in `return $x` is required by Javascript

  - Ignoring it will say that `return$x` is undefined
- The function name is automatic: I have no choice over it
- Picking only PHP or only Javascript will only reduce the code in 1 byte, and would reduce the fun-factor by half
- May work with other languages

---

Old answer (48 bytes):

```
alert(Function('$x',`return $x+${prompt()};`));
```

Old invalid answer:

```
y=>''+Function('$x',`return $x+${y};`)
```

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Done. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby to [Thue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 139 bytes

Not as short as i thought it should be, but I will post anyway. Thue may not be the best language for golfing in.

```
10.times{|n|puts "#{n}+::=#{n==9?'+':''}#{(n+1)%10}\n#{n}|::=|*#{n}\n>#{n}::=~#{n}"};puts "_::=:::\n||::=<\n<*::=<>\n::=\n|_#{'+'*($*[0]).to_i}|"
```

Takes a command-line augment in ruby, and regular input in Thue.

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously to K, 4 bytes

```
'+,+
```

Everyone else is posting "to K" answers, I might as well too. Takes input in the form of a string (`"3.14"`).

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=272b2c2b&input=%223.14%22)

Answer (score 1):

## Python to Lisp - <s>34</s> 36 Bytes

```
print"(lambda (x) (+ x %s))"%input()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go → LOLCODE, 192 bytes

```golang
package main;import."fmt";func main(){a:="";Scanln(&a);Println("HAI1.3\nHOW IZ I ADDIN YR X\nI HAS A VAR\nVAR R SUM OF X AN "+a+"\nVISIBLE VAR\nIF U SAY SO\nKTHXBYE")}
```

the resulting output compiles with `lci`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 → Go, 89 bytes

```
print('package main;import"fmt";func main(){a()};func a(x int)int{fmt.Println(x+'+input()+')}')
```

also a full program which compiles/runs with any of `go build`, `go install` or `go run`.

if we allow just a function (which is an error/will not compile) then **47 bytes**:

```
print('func a(x int)int{return x+'+input()+'}')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go → Python (any version), 109 bytes

```
package main;import"fmt";func main(){var a string;_,_=fmt.Scanln(&a);fmt.Println("def a(x):\n return x+"+a)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/) -> Python 3, <s>155</s> 153 bytes

```java
import java.util.Scanner;class Main{public static void main(String[] args){Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);System.out.println("lambda x:x+"+s.next());}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#LYsxDoMwDEWvYjElQs3I0KhH6MRYdTAQIVeJQbGhVIizU4ZM778vvZPSPGWFD67oFqXo2h6ZQ/Z9RBF4IvE@L12kHkRRL6wTDZCu37SaicfXGzCPYvdSgjw4fKGYaX@iITli68ucFnXzVWpkU0VM3YCw3be6qsVx2NRY64/jPG9N8wc)

Not exactly a winning combination but it gave me a chance to practice using java.

Saved 2+ bytes thanks to @WheatWizard

Comment: You could probably save bytes by writing out to a python lambda function.  `"lambda x:x+"`.

Comment: @WheatWizard thanks

Comment: You don't need spaces on the sides of your equals signs add well.

Comment: Why did you remove the target language from the title?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I think this was my first or second answer on this site, so I didn’t really know what I was doing. It’s fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) to [J](https://jsoftware.com), 4 bytes

```
„&+«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8Ne1Dq///NwYA)

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc) to Python, <strike>85 57</strike> 50 bytes

Borrowing @Oskar Skog's suggestions

```c
main(n){scanf("%d",&n);printf("lambda m:m+%d",n);}
```

## Python 3 to C (gcc), 43 bytes

```python
print('i(p){printf("%d",p+'+input()+');}')
```

### Joke answers (I couldn't hold myself back)

#### 1. C (gcc) to C (gcc), 66 bytes

> `main(n){scanf("%d",&n);printf("i(p){printf('%s',p+%d);}","%d",n);}`

#### 2. Python 3 to Python 3, 30 bytes

> `print(f"lambda n:n+{input()}")`

Comment: This can be shortened to `main(n){scanf("%d",&n);printf("def i(x):return x+%d",n);}`.  This is K&R C, the default data type is int and you don't need to declare int-returning functions.

Comment: You can also use `lambda` which makes the output shorter as well.  `i=lambda x:x+y` is a drop-in replacement, but I think the question allows removing `i=` as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) to [Myby](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Myby), 14 bytes

```
$><<"+&"+$**""
```

```
C:\Myby>ruby -e "$><<'+&'+$**''" 3 > out  && myby -l out 3  
Nibbles: 4A 03
4 nibbles, 2 bytes
6
```

Myby is exactly J in this case, where one can bond an argument to a dyadic verb to create a monadic verb.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) to [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes (4 nibbles)

```
"+"$
```

[image]

Outputs the [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) function `+2` for input `2`.
[Try the Husk function online](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qKnxv7bR////DQ0A)

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) to [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4 bytes

```
:'+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/30pdu/j///9GAA)

Outputs the [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) function `+2` for input `2`.
Here's a [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) program that uses this function to add 2 to every elemnt of the input:

```
.$ +2
.$      # map over every element of the input
   +2   # using the function '+2'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal) to Vyxal, 2 bytes

```
θ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///cDu3//00B)

Takes input (for example 5) on stdin. Outputs `5+`, which adds 5 to the input when run as vyxal.

Answer (score 0):

## C# to Mathematica, <s>85</s> 81 bytes

```
using C=System.Console;class C{static void Main(){C.Write(C.ReadLine()+"+#&");}}
```

Outputs a Mathematica `Function` of form

```
n+#&
```

Comment: In the first programming language (C# in your case) you should write a full program (which reads input and produces output), not just a single function.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann "EDIT: Anonymous functions and lambda expressions are allowed!"

Comment: This is for the created function, not the creating one ... see my comment at the question about this and the OP's answer to it (which were both later than this edit).

Comment: Save 4 bytes by replacing `WriteLine` with `Write`

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth to C++, 32 bytes

```
%"[](int x){return x+%d;}"Q
```

Just a Pyth version of my Python one.

Answer (score 0):

## Python to Pyth, 20 bytes

```
print"L+%db"%input()
```

Basically, it prints out a lambda function (L) that takes in the argument (b, implicit variable) and adds the input from the Python program.

Comment: @BadCatEye fixed it..

Answer (score 0):

## [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) → [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 8 bytes

```
echo;%1+
```

Fun fact: you don't have to use a space to separate `echo` from the text to be echo-ed, but you can pick from a whole series of different characters. For example: `.`, `,`, `:`, `;` and some others.

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ) to [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
;?A+@+
```

Given `n=3`, this will output the Jelly code `3+`. When another number is passed to this link, it will add 3 to it. [Try that online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2@s/f//fzMA)

The QBIC code:

```
;   Read cmd line param as A$
?A  PRINT A$
+@+ plus the string literal '+'
    The string literal is auto-closed by QBIC at EOF.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java -> C (GCC) <s>144</s> 134 bytes

```
class m{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(String.format("a(b){return %s+b;}",a[0]));}}
```

Takes the number(string, it is supposed to be a number, no error checking) as the first argument and prints the function to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure -> JavaScript, 14 bytes

```clj
#(str"a=>a+"%)
```

An anonymous function in Clojure that returns an anonymous function in JavaScript (and potentially a few other languages). `%` is the implicit `n`.

```clj
(#(str"a=>a+"%) 3)

"a=>a+3"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell -> Clojure, 25 bytes

```hs
\n->"#(+ % "++show n++")"
```

Anonymous Haskell function which takes `n`, and returns an anonymous Clojure function.

```
let f = \n->"#(+ % "++show n++")"

f 3

#(+ % 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

## sB~ -> Befunge, 7 bytes

```
iN?N;`+
```

Explained:

```
i N 'input N
?N;`+ 'print N and "+"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) to [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
᠀\+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////4YKGGO3//w2NAA)

This takes the input at a string, pushes a plus sign, and outputs everything on the stack. It prints `<input>+`, which adds the input to a number in Vyxal.

Comment: Is the output a *function* in Vyxal, though?

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html) to Haskell, 12 bytes

```
?[+)][(]nrnn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b/7fPlpbMzZaIzavKC/v/38A)

Could be -1 byte if input can be taken on the stack, instead of prompting the user.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) to JavaScript, 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an integer string

```
i+i¨ÔiÍin
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=aStpqNRpzWlu&input=Ijgi)

It was only 2 bytes longer than the boring literal string version (below), so why not?!

```
i"n=>n+
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=aSJuPT5uKw&input=Ijgi)

And going the other way, from JS to Japt is only 8 bytes:

```
n=>"+"+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k5JW0k7739yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahoWm5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) → [Red](https://red-lang.org), 24 bytes

```
[ [I func[x][x +${}]I] ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owd7QYE8_dyuFzLyS1KKC_JzEklSF7NSivNQcBWsu46WlJWm6FjuiFaI9FdJK85KjK2KjKxS0VaprYz1jFWIh0kuSE3NyIMwFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey) -> ARM Thumb machine code, 7 bytes

```
$c."0pG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P9fJVlPyaDA/f9/M0MA)

```
$c."0pG
$c       print char value of...
  .      ...an integer from stdin
   "0pG  then print "0pG"
```

Works with values 0-255, with integers typed in base 10.

This will encode to `NN 30 70 47`, which results in the following Thumb code:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .globl func
    .thumb_func
    // c callable
    // int func(int x);
func:
    // add N to r0   NN 30   .0
    adds    r0, #N 
    // return        70 47   pG
    bx      lr
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev) to Forth, 78 bytes

```go
package main
import."fmt"
func main(){x:="";Scanln(&x);Printf(": N %s + ;",x)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6Fjf9ChKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSvSU0nJLlLjSSvOSwcIamtUVVrZKStbByYl5OXkaahWa1gFFmXklaRpKVgp-CqrFCtoK1ko6FZq1EFOhhi9YaAphAAA)

Outputs a word `: N x + ;` that expects an integer on the stack, and adds it to the input.

### Joke Answers

#### [Go](https://go.dev) to Go, 95 bytes

```go
package main
import."fmt"
func main(){x:="";Scanln(&x);Printf("func(n int)int{return n+%s}",x)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjfjCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSvSU0nJLlLjSSvOSwcIamtUVVrZKStbByYl5OXkaahWa1gFFmXklaRpKIEUaeQpAjiYQVxellpQW5SnkaasW1yrpVGjWQqyB2rZgoSmEAQA)

Outputs an anonymous Go function `func(n int)int{return n+x}`.

#### [Go](https://go.dev) returning a function, 114 bytes

```go
import(."fmt";."strconv")
func f()func(int)int{x,n:="",0
Scanln(&x)
n,_=Atoi(x)
return func(k int)int{return k+n}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjeLMnML8otKNPSU0nJLlKz1lIpLipLz88qUNLnSSvOSFdI0NEG0RmZeiSYQV1fo5FnZKinpGHAFJyfm5eRpqFVocuXpxNs6luRnagDZRaklpUV5CmBN2QowbVDRbO282lqozVpg80FO0dCsBlmmYGULso4roAioA2gyUEjD0EBTkwuqY8FCUwgDAA)

Returns a Go function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) → [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/), 3 bytes

```
'++
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi9W1tZcUJyUXQ_kLFhpDGAA) (Thunno 2 program)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Y@////6YA) (Jelly function)

The Thunno 2 program appends `+` to the input.