# Parse Ternary Lambda Calculus for correctness

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, parsing, lambda-calculus

[Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard) has once tried to come up with [a parsing problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/233453/78410) unsuitable for regex, but it failed due to [Anders Kaseorg's Perl regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233465/78410). This is the second attempt. Now that we know that Perl regex is far more powerful than we've imagined, this challenge aims to be un-golfy for it instead.

### Introduction

A **lambda term** is recursively defined as follows:

- A *variable* is a lambda term.
- A *lambda abstraction* of a lambda term is a lambda term.
- A *function application* of two lambda terms is a lambda term.

This is concisely written as follows (where `e` is a term and `x` is any valid variable name):

```
e = x | λx. e | e e
```

A variable is often a string (as in Wheat Wizard's challenge), but it suffers from name shadowing problem. To avoid it and for an easier encoding, we use [de Bruijn indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) instead. In this notation, a variable is replaced with a positive integer, which is equal to "the number of binders that are in scope between that occurrence and its corresponding binder". The grammar is simplified to the following:

```
e = i | λ e | e e
```

Some examples in this notation:

- `λx. x` is written as `λ 1`, as the inner `x` binds to the first (and only) `λ` in scope.
- `λx. λy. x` is written as `λ λ 2`, as the inner `x` binds to the second `λ`, counting from the closest one.
- `λx. λy. x (λz. z y)` is written as `λ λ 2 (λ 1 2)`.

### Ternary lambda calculus

This is an encoding of a lambda term similar to [Binary lambda calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html), but in ternary (a string of digits 0, 1, and 2). A lambda term written using de Bruijn indexes is converted to Ternary lambda calculus as follows:

- A variable of index `i` is converted to binary (using 0 and 1), and then a `2` is added at the end. Since `i` is positive, this always starts with a 1.
- A lambda abstraction `λ e` is recursively converted to `0<e>`, where `<e>` denotes the Ternary conversion of `e`.
- A function application `e1 e2` is recursively converted to `2<e1><e2>`.

Examples:

- `λ 1` is encoded to `012`. (`1` encodes to `12`, and a single lambda abstraction adds a `0`)
- `λ λ 2` is encoded to `00102`.
- `λ λ 2 (λ 1 2)` is encoded to `0021020212102`.

The original BLC requires that the lambda term is **closed**, i.e. all variables are bound to some lambda abstraction. This means the variable index `i` is limited by the current "lambda depth"; in particular, no variables may appear at the top level at all. Using the lambda depth (a non-negative integer) as the context, the grammar to match becomes the following:

```
TermAtDepth(d) =
    bin(i) "2" where 1 ≤ i ≤ d
  | "0" TermAtDepth(d+1)
  | "2" TermAtDepth(d) TermAtDepth(d)

e = TermAtDepth(0)
```

### Code

```haskell
tlc :: Int -> Parser ()
tlc depth =
  do
    choice
      [ do
        char '1'
        idx <- many $ charBy (`elem` "01")
        guard $ foldl (\x y->x*2+y) 1 [fromEnum x-48|x<-idx] <= depth
        char '2'
        return ()
      , do
        char '0'
        tlc (depth + 1)
      , do
        char '2'
        tlc depth
        tlc depth
      ]
    return ()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVTbattAEH3XVwxOIavaDpboQwm2wUkbCDQQaN8c46ytlS2yurBaJzJNv92dvclrue1LQ5B3Zs7MnrntltYvjPPDz@EFfKPFZkc3DO44a7IVZ/dFLWmxZjVcDH8FWV6VQsKjYHyXMNhmSVZsAgACdFXjb@gQt2UhRcmvZlXFszWV2SvTMJ6lchbjcQAzLpkotAnI1VX4J/eHsqCJdnwts0S7IT2R@NgvVFIFNAACZDwNz@y3Wyq0NatnvNpSDQgK9ib3FYNHKmomgMIE9VYg36XA5GA4hbk9D4CGC3SjmNQerq@Pfgj6C9yCiYVWIdT6lgp/gyCz1YW7XbGWpXAR37ZMqIKlOa0gRZsfQLm3ND8YDNGfFh6GUHnRvS50b6h2gkFzGpPAE9ReOrVNpwkXqmpguwjpkVUUHs/xKUV9hE7QpLRqNAiWRwMQrMYg4yHGsrgTRKwRsUHEoHxau2ByJwoHS3Uog7aQ0KuFHqluFRx1mE4nGOC/6HfZ2wFILcRj7tPyt6FDjuWV3J93aKmbozoC4KUQwfh92kpxd1pO82hrDf2@AlvBJ0bMauEsw2QKVnC9RqVjmfs09VQZjTJhCViRWJsdHqsMgjWu5o1eJ6K2VNG6KUseqoO9Rm@vxVWCJWqWmb@sG9UPxwRQBELhGlZuEgHmQFZqIeHdi0Bh4fBYyBa6MKQUJceoS8SujOVEmskEa2arh27Hx8A6GoVDKFcp6CtDm46hLiwzrDb6zl1tF54/dQDlmpY8wRnAPodmOA6Sr5XrfSE9HxIGSp@wSm61n51aE6mtizfLOrPL6LJVZEmjZjqnxR5nx2X7zDjLn6E3inphC9XvsnqOkBwH8tTAfjhtPsb9fQgRzFNR5l@LXQ7N8NPn92Y8xNALGE8MvQ6D@PJst91Fg3O@oyNa5UtMwn2I/uETn/qckuhqzJC0TA7pjvMHKtdbqEyl8UnHuGz9gvmbdW8NbiiNeU56vQEs8R2dwA@xOxqWqLijvGZBTrMCBc0Yd@RhCaTCoZFwBcd7iaI4Ck2Cc9WJuBeYVHujUTTypRhF/MSnWvcXjbr6GJHqgx7m69nbgzKcCL6MbMy/0SwOvwE)

### Challenge

Given a ternary string (a string that entirely consists of digits 0, 1, and 2), determine if it is a valid Ternary lambda calculus code.

You may take the input as a string or a list of digit values. The input may be empty, and your code should give a false output on it.

For output, you can choose to

- output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
- use two distinct, fixed values to represent true (affirmative) or false (negative) respectively.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
-- Truthy
012
00102
0021020212102
000000000010102
00002210022112122112102

-- Falsy
(empty)
2112
2112112
012012012
```

Comment: Nice parsing library you got there :)

Comment: @WheatWizard Yeah, it's extremely easy to use. I love it :D

Comment: Can we use an error to signal false (or true)?

Comment: @NickKennedy Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
4ŀ1Ẹ?‘}
1;œṡ2Ṫ0ḢḄ<ɗ?
ñ⁹ñ
Ḣ‘$ŀ
ç1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/kaIPhw1077B81zKjlMrQ@OvnhzoVGD3euMni4Y9HDHS02J6fbcx3e@Khx5@GNXEAhoDKVow1ch5cb/g971LTmcDuX9aOGOQq6dgqPGuZaA7kPd2853A6Uifz/3wAIjIwMwYShkSGENDDiMjAEYgMwywAkACQg4nBgaADjY9PPBWKACRANNA2CAA)

A full program taking a list of integers and returning an empty list (falsy) for valid and a non-empty list (truthy) for invalid.

### Explanation

#### Helper link 1 (handles 0…)

```
   Ẹ?        | If the list is non-empty:
4ŀ   ‘}      | - Call helper link 4 with the depth increased by 1
  1          | - Else return 1
```

#### Helper link 2 (handles 1…)

```
1;           | Prepend 1
  œṡ2        | Split at 2s
       ḢḄ<ɗ? | If the first part of the list converted from binary is less than the depth:
     Ṫ       | - Return the second part of the list
      0      | - Else return 0
```

#### Helper link 3 (handles 2…)

```
ñ⁹ñ          | Call helper link 4 twice, preserving depth
```

#### Helper link 4 (handles next part)

```
Ḣ‘$ŀ         | Call the helper link indicated by the first list member plus 1, preserving the same depth
```

#### Main link

```
ç1           | Call helper link 4 with 1 as the right argument (depth)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 86 bytes

```haskell
q x=cx[do χ 1;k<-my$kB(<2);gu$x>lF(pl.db)1 k;χ 2,χ 0*>q(x+1),χ 2*>q x*>q x]
x1$q 1
```

*Takes input as a list of integers*

hgl is a library I am making for golfing in Haskell.  It has pretty decent parsing capabilities.  It however does not yet have a function to convert from binary.  Which is a bit of a problem for this answer.  The code I came up with to do the task is `lF(pl.db)0`.

This code follows same structure of the parsing code given in the question.  That's because both parsing libraries are written by me and use the same theoretic underpinning.

We use `cx` which is analygous to the `choice` in the question selecting between 3 options.

```haskell
q x = cx
  [ do
    χ 1
    k<-my$kB(<2)
    gu$x>lF(pl.db)1 k
    χ 2
  , χ 0*>q(x+1)
  , χ 2*>q x*>q x
  ]
```

The last two don't use `do` notation since it would cost bytes, but they can be written with it.

```haskell
q x = cx
  [ do
    χ 1
    k<-my$kB(<2)
    gu$x>lF(pl.db)1 k
    χ 2
  , do
    χ 0
    q(x+1)
  , do
    χ 2
    q x
    q x
  ]
```

As one might guess now `χ` parses a single integer. We have `gu` which is `guard`, `m` which is `fmap` and `kB` which is the `charBy` function.

The remainder is `lF(pl.db)1` which converts from binary.  In regular haskell this is

```
foldl((+).(*2))1
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 121 bytes

```javascript
f=d=>(s=s.slice(1),s[0]<1?f(d+1):s[0]>1?f(d)&f(d):(s=s.replace(/[01]+/,x=>parseInt(x,2)>d||''))[0]>1),a=>f(0,s=0+a)&!s[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBboMwDIbve4v20MYipU6O1ZKd9wyA1AgCYktDhNHUSn13moRtlvXZv/3bX@bHUDuPYTlRGDs73yb/bR/roNjaq05pRopKcmNrmQBOFTbv4qNnXSHgkpTOCg4Jl2yebXAm2s8ViqY487vSwcxkP/3C7lyC7p7P4xEgHwM3SvcMOSksDBx2VIlmhbd28jQ5W7ppYHsUsvaIAnORsUbIX/kXAv8HMu4SomdjWtQ@tRtzE79uWXsh9yUFNy7X2l/LmwlsAFhf)

The first function called, which is the unnamed arrow function at the end of the code, calls `f` while using an extra argument to initialise `s` to the provided string with `0` prepended.

`f` does the main parsing, removing characters from `s` as it goes, returning false on failure. It begins by unconditionally removing one character, which is the reason for the prepended `0`.

The first two cases are simple: `s[0]<1` (begins with `0`) leads to `f(d+1)`, a recursive call with depth increased, and `s[0]>1` (begins with `2`) leads to `f(d)&f(d)`, parsing two subterms.

The final case covers `s` beginning with `1`, and also `s` being empty (in which case `s[0]` is `undefined`, making both comparisons false). It uses the regexp `/^[01]+/` to pick out the binary number. The replacer function (`x=>parseInt(x,2)>d||''`) checks whether the number is too high, returning `true` if it is and an empty string otherwise. The function then checks whether the remaining string begins with a digit greater than 1; if the number was too high, it begins with `t` and that is false. In the case of `s` being empty, no replacement occurs, and `""[0]>1` is also false.

Finally, back in the unnamed arrow function, `!s[1]` checks whether the whole string was parsed, in which case all but one character will have been removed from it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 106 bytes

```haskell
(y%q)x|2:z<-q=[z|y<x]|w:z<-q=(2*y+w)%z$x|1>0=[]
x#(z:y)=[(1+x)#y,1%y$x,x#y>>=(x#)]!!z
x#_=[]
([[]]==).(1#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvRCoMwDEXf9xVKFdrZDdNHsf5IKcOH4WQqug1MS/@9qzqGjHFDcpJ7c6uf92vXeU9NOjF0orDlaZLKOlOidvO2UnE02cxSm6CDKpdKH5BQWxgmFYUMGTEcUpMgR2KqSlIkTMexDanLEm4kVUprKdmZAmG@r9tBjo92eCV9PUZNpFTOgQvNw1wo//Kv4I8vgmBHsPY9b/lQn9P6vFi7rrV/Aw)

Quite different from my Haskell + hgl answer, and still decently short, all things being considered.  This uses a more bootleg parse than that, but if you squint you can see the similarities.

Answer (score 2):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 86 bytes

```
d#(0:x)=(d+1)#x
d#(1:i++[2])|all(<2)i&&foldl((+).(2*))1 i<=d=1
d#(2:x++y)=d#x*d#y
(0#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrNCsMgEITvPoUghN1sW1yPEp8k5CARQWp/SCgo9N2tbS/hg@EbZtbXttXz01/XvbWgQNuCDgIxqiJ6Z5uIZrPg2@cMk8E0DPGRQwYgvIAZEVmmyQXH37uxhaiiC6qMQVURHWiF7ebTXToZ5axPf0yHD8a/PHpfliY@)

Returns `1` for truth, and nothing otherwise.